# Is there a way to get 'Ultimate Thread Group' parameter?

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

I'm new with jmeter.

I ran a test that at the end it generates a dashboard report.
Is there way to see the load details (no. of threads, initial Delay, Hold Load...)?
If not, is there a way to get 'Ultimate Thread Group' parameters so I can print it to DB?

Thanks
Dotan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the code like:

```
if (ctx.getThreadNum() == 1 && vars.getIteration() == 1) {
    ctx.getThreadGroup().getProperty("ultimatethreadgroupdata").getObjectValue().eachWithIndex { entry, index ->
        log.info('----------------------------------------------')
        log.info('Line number ' + (index + 1) + ' parameters:')
        log.info('Start threads count: ' + entry.get(0).value)
        log.info('Initial delay: ' + entry.get(1).value)
        log.info('Startup time: ' + entry.get(2).value)
        log.info('Hold load for: ' + entry.get(3).value)
        log.info('Shutdown time: ' + entry.get(4).value)
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) to learn what do these `ctx` and `vars` objects mean.